# make a matrix from a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with a list in python that I need to convert to a matrix. The list is always random so I have no Idea how to make it. Here's an example :

```
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '\n', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '\n', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', '1', '1', '1', '\n', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '\n', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '\n', '\n']
```

And I want it to look like a matrix so that for each '\n' it would make a new list :

```
[['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], ['1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1'], ['1', ' ', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', '1', '1', '1'], ['1', ' ', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1'], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']]
```

I have no idea how to make this so somebody could help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

def split_at_el(arr, el):
    return [list(j) for i,j in groupby(arr,lambda x: x == el) if not i]

x = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '\n', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '\n', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', '1', '1', '1', '\n', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '\n', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '\n', '\n']

print(split_at_el(x, '\n'))
```

Output:

```
[['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], ['1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1'], ['1', ' ', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', '1', '1', '1'], ['1', ' ', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1'], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']]
```

Also works for any longer strings:

```
>>> split_at_el(['hello', 'there', '\n', 'more', 'strings'], '\n')
[['hello', 'there'], ['more', 'strings']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use list comprehension

```
[list(k) for k in "".join(c).split("\n") if k]
```